# Angular 8 @ViewChild Template Variable Error - Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Tags: angular

I can't seem to get `@ViewChild` to work with a template variable in Angular 8, it is always coming back as `undefined`.

Please see my example below.  I plan to add the code for an mdbModal here once I figure out the `ViewChild` issue, I'm just using the input as an example.

The `console.log(this.hi.nativeElement);` line causes the error:

> Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

**view.component.html**

```
<button *ngIf="caseDetail.statusId != 1" type="button" mdbBtn (click)="showClaimStatusModal()">Claim Status</button>
<app-claim-status-modal></app-claim-status-modal>
```

**app.module.ts**
    import { ClaimStatusModalComponent } from './views/claim-status-modal/claim-status-modal.component';

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ClaimStatusModalComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: ClaimStatusModalComponent, useValue: new     ClaimStatusModalComponent() }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**view.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ClaimStatusModalComponent } from '@app/views/claim-status-modal/claim-status-modal.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-view',
  templateUrl: './view.component.html'
})
export class ViewComponent implements OnInit {  
  constructor(private claimStatusModalComponent: ClaimStatusModalComponent) { }
  ngOnInit() {
      //Subscribes to observable to get caseDetail
  }

  showClaimStatusModal() {
    this.claimStatusModalComponent.show();
  }
}
```

**claim-status-modal.component.html**

```
<input id="hi" #hi type="text" value="Hi" />
```

**claim-status-modal.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-claim-status-modal',
  templateUrl: './claim-status-modal.component.html'    
})
export class ClaimStatusModalComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('hi', {static: false}) hi:  any;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
  }

  show() {
    console.log(this.hi);
    console.log(this.hi.nativeElement);    
  }
}
```

Comment: out of the two component which one of them are you considering as child and trying to read property from it.

Comment: I'm really curious to understand why exactly you are trying to bend the rules of Angular and injecting a Component as a dependency?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to set name for your component `#hi`:

```
<app-claim-status-modal #hi></app-claim-status-modal>
```

Comment: the name #hi is on the input in claim-status-modal.component.html rather than the directive.  Also I just tried putting it on the directive and I get the same error.

Comment: @fosbie try to write `ngAfterViewInit() { console.log(`ngAfterViewInit`this.hi);
  }` and what you see?

Comment: It's still undefined

Comment: @fosbie could you create  stackblitz example?